# How many cards do you have to have in your hand to finish a meld that has 6 cards in Hand and Foot canasta?

Tags: canasta

If there is 6 Jack's in a meld, how many Jack's do you have to have in your hand?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking about adding to that six-card set of Jacks with cards from your hand? A meld cannot hold more than seven cards. So to "finish" a six-card meld, you only need one card.

Answer (score 1):

A meld cannot hold more than seven cards. So to "finish" a six-card Jack meld, you only need one more Jack.

From the [rules on Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/handfoot.html):

> A meld is a set of from three to seven cards of equal rank placed face up on the table. A meld cannot have fewer than three cards or more than seven.

and

> A meld cannot contain more than seven cards, and a partnership is not allowed to have two incomplete melds of the same rank, but if you complete a pile, you can then start another meld of the same rank.

If you're trying to pick up from the discard pile to complete the meld, the rules go on to handle this case explicitly:

> Therefore if you have an incomplete meld of five or six cards on the table, you will not be able to pick up a card of that rank from the discard pile unless you have enough cards of that rank to finish the first seven card pile and make a new three card meld of the same rank. These cards must all come from your holding and the top card of the pile - again you are not allowed to make use of other cards you are about to pick up from the discard pile to satisfy the requirement.